# Twitter record size

Tags: json, optimization, twitter, nosql, cassandra

Sorry for maybe stupid question;)

I am trying to model records like if they were modeled for twitter. It is interesting for me how big or small they are? Is it normal that they can be bigger than 512 bytes per record?

And what methods do you know for optimization records within json documents? I mean especial for json;) Maybe some links?

Thanks;)

Comment: Have you checked the twissandra project? You might get something useful there. Other than that your question needs to be more specific. Have you written any code? Are you stuck at some point?

Comment: @Sagar please write the answer about twissandra. I'll accept it;)

Answer (score 1):

To analyze the worst case:
If you store data in utf8, it's conceivable that having all 3-byte characters means 480 bytes.

A utf8 may even be [4 bytes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) (4*160=640).  I'm not sure this is an edge-case worth protecting against.